# Problem in ES6 without using array divisible by 10

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem that i want to solve without using an array

Print the numbers from 1 to 100. If the number is divisible by 10, print "Hello"

**Code**

```
Array.from(Array(100), (_,i) => console.log(i+1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using for loop:

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  if(i % 10 === 0) console.log("Hello");
}
```

Comment: There are no array functions here, can you clarify?

Comment: He is not using any array functions

Answer (score 0):

A little more edits to your current solution

```js
Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) =>
  console.log(i + 1, (i + 1) % 10 === 0 ? "Hello" : "")
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to not using Array functions?

Comment: @Joseph did you mentioned "array methods"?

Answer (score 0):

Use **for**

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  (i % 10 === 0) ? console.log( i, "Hello") : console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more concise do this:

```js
Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => console.log((i + 1) % 10 === 0 ? "hello" : i + 1))
```